# Quarkus and Redis Cluster "Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster"

Tags: redis, quarkus, redis-cluster, quarkus-native

I have quarkus native application that connects to Redis Cluster (using quarkus-redis-client) and is doing a lot set/getdel commands based on consumed kafka events.
My Redis cluster contains 10 nodes, 3 masters and 7 replicas and I connect to it using tls (rediss://)

I have this in my `.env` file next to my app:

```
QUARKUS_REDIS_HOSTS=rediss://nodey01:26379,rediss://nodey02:26379,rediss://nodey03:26379,rediss://nodey04:26379,rediss://nodey05:26379,rediss://nodex01:26379,rediss://nodex02:26379,rediss://nodex03:26379,rediss://nodex04:26379,rediss://nodex05:26379
QUARKUS_REDIS_TLS_KEY_CERTIFICATE_PEM=true
QUARKUS_REDIS_TLS_KEY_CERTIFICATE_PEM_CERTS=/path/to/redis.cer
QUARKUS_REDIS_TLS_KEY_CERTIFICATE_PEM_KEYS=/path/to/redis.pem
QUARKUS_REDIS_TIMEOUT=10s
QUARKUS_REDIS_RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS=3
```

and following in my `application.properties`

```
quarkus.redis.client-type=cluster
quarkus.redis.replicas=share
quarkus.redis.max-pool-size=15
quarkus.redis.tls.enabled=true
```

And to my problem - from now and then (it varies, sometimes it happens once a 2/3 hours, sometimes every 20/30 minutes) application logs:

```json
{
  "timestamp": "2023-07-24T13:50:14.987+02:00",
  "sequence": 97,
  "loggerClassName": "io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.i18n.ProviderLogging_$logger",
  "loggerName": "io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.provider",
  "level": "ERROR",
  "message": "SRMSG00200: The method x.y.z.KafkaConsumer#consume has thrown an exception",
  "threadName": "executor-thread-26",
  "threadId": 71,
  "mdc": {},
  "ndc": "",
  "hostName": "x-y-z-app-5d66d5d685-m4fzz",
  "processId": 198,
  "exception": {
    "refId": 1,
    "exceptionType": "java.util.concurrent.CompletionException",
    "message": "io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster",
    "frames": [
      {
        "class": "io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniBlockingAwait",
        "method": "await",
        "line": 79
      },
      {
        "class": "io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait",
        "method": "atMost",
        "line": 65
      },
      {
        "class": "io.quarkus.redis.runtime.datasource.BlockingStringCommandsImpl",
        "method": "getdel",
        "line": 46
      },
      {
        "class": "x.y.z.EventHandler",
        "method": "handleEvent",
        "line": 84
      },
      {
        "class": "x.y.z.KafkaConsumer",
        "method": "consume",
        "line": 35
      },
      {
        "class": "x.y.z.KafkaConsumer_ClientProxy",
        "method": "consume"
      },
      {
        "class": "x.y.z.KafkaConsumer_SmallRyeMessagingInvoker_consume_7b6b03028e49841c0cf07599f38fe59284b433a1",
        "method": "invoke"
      },
      {
        "class": "io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.AbstractMediator",
        "method": "lambda$invokeBlocking$4",
        "line": 125
      },
      {
        "class": "io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer",
        "method": "accept",
        "line": 21
      },
      {
        "class": "io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateWithEmitter",
        "method": "subscribe",
        "line": 22
      },
      {
        "class": "io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni",
        "method": "subscribe",
        "line": 36
      },
      {
        "class": "io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromDeferredSupplier",
        "method": "subscribe",
        "line": 36
      },
      {
        "class": "io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni",
        "method": "subscribe",
        "line": 36
      },
      {
        "class": "io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe",
        "method": "withSubscriber",
        "line": 51
      },
      {
        "class": "io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe",
        "method": "with",
        "line": 110
      },
      {
        "class": "io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe",
        "method": "with",
        "line": 88
      },
      {
        "class": "io.vertx.mutiny.core.Context$1",
        "method": "handle",
        "line": 170
      },
      {
        "class": "io.vertx.mutiny.core.Context$1",
        "method": "handle",
        "line": 168
      },
      {
        "class": "io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase",
        "method": "lambda$null$0",
        "line": 137
      },
      {
        "class": "io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal",
        "method": "dispatch",
        "line": 264
      },
      {
        "class": "io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase",
        "method": "lambda$executeBlocking$1",
        "line": 135
      },
      {
        "class": "io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue",
        "method": "run",
        "line": 76
      },
      {
        "class": "io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14",
        "method": "runWith",
        "line": 576
      },
      {
        "class": "org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task",
        "method": "run",
        "line": 2513
      },
      {
        "class": "org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody",
        "method": "run",
        "line": 1538
      },
      {
        "class": "org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable",
        "method": "run",
        "line": 29
      },
      {
        "class": "org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable",
        "method": "run",
        "line": 29
      },
      {
        "class": "io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable",
        "method": "run",
        "line": 30
      },
      {
        "class": "java.lang.Thread",
        "method": "run",
        "line": 833
      },
      {
        "class": "com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads",
        "method": "threadStartRoutine",
        "line": 775
      },
      {
        "class": "com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads",
        "method": "pthreadStartRoutine",
        "line": 203
      }
    ],
    "causedBy": {
      "exception": {
        "refId": 2,
        "exceptionType": "io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable",
        "message": "Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster",
        "frames": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All Redis nodes are working propperly - it's probably just some connection issues between my app and specific Redis nodes

Other instances of the app (same app, but cunsuming different, less demanding kafka topics) works perfectly

But, to be honest, bad connection between my app and redis is not my biggest concern right now - although I will do my best to mitigate it.

My biggest problem is, I don't understand why it does need connection to all Redis nodes?
I specifically set Redis Cluster, so in times of maintanence, my cluster would still be operational (and it is) and my app **wouldn't suffer downtime** because of it.

But now it seems, that shutting down even one replica node of my cluster, will result in my app downtime - even though redis cluster itself is still "a ok" (besides missing one replica node)

I'm turning to you, because maybe my configuration is flawed?

I found https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20963 but wasn't really helpfull, still, switched to newest quarkus-redis-client but no change

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-redis-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and this https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client/issues/223, but it doesn't seems to be the case, because I'm setting `cluster-announce-ip` and `cluster-announce-port`, and other instances of the app are working just right with the same Redis cluster

I also played with `QUARKUS_REDIS_RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS` and `QUARKUS_REDIS_TIMEOUT` with no luck

---

PS1 So I did some testing

I have 2 instances of my app (all the same configuration), will call them instances `A` and `B` - `A` is constantly trying to write/read using Redis, whereas `B` is "chilling", not doing anything (no new messages on its Kafka topic)

And 1 Spring application (Reddison client) using same Redis cluster but without TLS (just user/password), will call it `S` - it's different app, REST one, so it is not really comparable but I mention it simply to show how Spring is doing with similar situations.
It has following configuration:

```yaml
spring:
  redis:
    username: REDACTED
    password: REDACTED
    cluster:
      nodes:
        - nodey01:26379
        - nodey02:26379
        - nodey03:26379
        - nodey04:26379
        - nodey05:26379
        - nodex01:26379
        - nodex02:26379
        - nodex03:26379
        - nodex04:26379
        - nodex05:26379
      max-redirects: 5
```

For more context, all these apps and Redis cluster are running on Kubernetes clusters with Liveness/Readiness probes (`A` and `B` once every 10s `/q/health/live` and `/q/health/ready` are GETted; for `S` `/management/health` is GETted)

---

My first test was to kill one of the Redis replica node and the following happened:

`A` failed with the same error as above and 3 failed Liveness probes resulting in restart

`B` didn't log same error as `A`, but that's because it is not consuming any kafka events at the moment. It did however log one bad response for Liveness probe

```json
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T10:00:08.779+02:00","sequence":136,"loggerClassName":"io.smallrye.health.HealthLogging_$logger","loggerName":"io.smallrye.health","level":"INFO","message":"SRHCK01001: Reporting health down status: {\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"checks\":[{\"name\":\"SmallRye Reactive Messaging - readiness check\",\"status\":\"UP\",\"data\":{\"kafka\":\"[OK]\"}},{\"name\":\"Redis connection health check\",\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"data\":{\"reason\":\"client [<default>]: io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster\"}},{\"name\":\"Elasticsearch cluster health check\",\"status\":\"UP\",\"data\":{\"status\":\"green\"}}]}","threadName":"executor-thread-1","threadId":32,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-7795d6ff5d-dwxrr","processId":198}
```

but recovers after that without restarting (Kubernetes need 3 failed probes to restart pod - here, after 1 failed probe, application recoverd and did report itself as healthy)

`S` logged every 30s that it's  trying to reconnect to it, but was stil operational and without any failed probes

---

My second test was to kill one of the Redis master nodes, to stimulate cluster going down for a while, and recovering (mind that it takes less than second for Redis cluster to "fix" itself - switch from replica to master - after such failure). Here is how it looks from Redis perspective:

```
1:S 25 Jul 2023 08:10:14.098 * FAIL message received from b35fb605020fd10c7a6d66febb5f92265e34b366 about a36d4082b1e650b3a11dbd03e610a120f132fd7c
1:S 25 Jul 2023 08:10:14.098 # Cluster state changed: fail
1:S 25 Jul 2023 08:10:14.954 # Cluster state changed: ok
```

The results were the same - `A` failed and restarted; `B` did report once unhealthy state but recovered after that; `S` still functional, logging every 30s that it's trying to reconnect to missing node.

---

So, quarkus-redis-client is fine to recover after losing node from connection pool, but not when it's trying to use them at the moment?

Knowing that, I can probably try catch Redis getdel/set methods and workaround it somehow

---

PS2. So per @Clement suggestion I rerun some tests with only masters and it did actually help a little - because replicas were not in the server list/connection pool, losing them wouldn't crash the app, but, operating only on 3 out of 10 Redis nodes is also not really optimal in my opinion and problem was still applying when I simulate losing one of masters. Logs:

```json
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T12:30:46.832+02:00","sequence":108,"loggerClassName":"io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.i18n.ProviderLogging_$logger","loggerName":"io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.provider","level":"ERROR","message":"SRMSG00200: The method x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer#consume has thrown an exception","threadName":"executor-thread-1","threadId":32,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-instance-a-7b8bc8f87b-6254q","processId":198,"exception":{"refId":1,"exceptionType":"java.util.concurrent.CompletionException","message":"io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster","frames":[{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniBlockingAwait","method":"await","line":79},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait","method":"atMost","line":65},{"class":"io.quarkus.redis.runtime.datasource.BlockingStringCommandsImpl","method":"getdel","line":46},{"class":"x.y.z.app.EventHandler","method":"handleEvent","line":84},{"class":"x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer","method":"consume","line":35},{"class":"x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer_ClientProxy","method":"consume"},{"class":"x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer_SmallRyeMessagingInvoker_consume_7b6b03028e49841c0cf07599f38fe59284b433a1","method":"invoke"},{"class":"io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.AbstractMediator","method":"lambda$invokeBlocking$4","line":125},{"class":"io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer","method":"accept","line":21},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateWithEmitter","method":"subscribe","line":22},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni","method":"subscribe","line":36},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromDeferredSupplier","method":"subscribe","line":36},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni","method":"subscribe","line":36},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe","method":"withSubscriber","line":51},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe","method":"with","line":110},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe","method":"with","line":88},{"class":"io.vertx.mutiny.core.Context$1","method":"handle","line":170},{"class":"io.vertx.mutiny.core.Context$1","method":"handle","line":168},{"class":"io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase","method":"lambda$null$0","line":137},{"class":"io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal","method":"dispatch","line":264},{"class":"io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase","method":"lambda$executeBlocking$1","line":135},{"class":"io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue","method":"run","line":76},{"class":"io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14","method":"runWith","line":576},{"class":"org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task","method":"run","line":2513},{"class":"org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody","method":"run","line":1538},{"class":"org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable","method":"run","line":29},{"class":"org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable","method":"run","line":29},{"class":"io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable","method":"run","line":30},{"class":"java.lang.Thread","method":"run","line":833},{"class":"com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads","method":"threadStartRoutine","line":775},{"class":"com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads","method":"pthreadStartRoutine","line":203}],"causedBy":{"exception":{"refId":2,"exceptionType":"io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable","message":"Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster","frames":[]}}}}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T12:30:46.833+02:00","sequence":109,"loggerClassName":"io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.i18n.KafkaLogging_$logger","loggerName":"io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka","level":"ERROR","message":"SRMSG18203: A message sent to channel `kafka` has been nacked, fail-stop","threadName":"vert.x-eventloop-thread-1","threadId":38,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-instance-a-7b8bc8f87b-6254q","processId":198}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T12:30:46.833+02:00","sequence":110,"loggerClassName":"io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.i18n.KafkaLogging_$logger","loggerName":"io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka","level":"WARN","message":"SRMSG18228: A failure has been reported for Kafka topics '[heavy-kafka-topic]'","threadName":"vert.x-eventloop-thread-1","threadId":38,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-instance-a-7b8bc8f87b-6254q","processId":198,"exception":{"refId":1,"exceptionType":"java.util.concurrent.CompletionException","message":"io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster","frames":[{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniBlockingAwait","method":"await","line":79},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait","method":"atMost","line":65},{"class":"io.quarkus.redis.runtime.datasource.BlockingStringCommandsImpl","method":"getdel","line":46},{"class":"x.y.z.app.EventHandler","method":"handleEvent","line":84},{"class":"x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer","method":"consume","line":35},{"class":"x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer_ClientProxy","method":"consume"},{"class":"x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer_SmallRyeMessagingInvoker_consume_7b6b03028e49841c0cf07599f38fe59284b433a1","method":"invoke"},{"class":"io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.AbstractMediator","method":"lambda$invokeBlocking$4","line":125},{"class":"io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer","method":"accept","line":21},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateWithEmitter","method":"subscribe","line":22},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni","method":"subscribe","line":36},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromDeferredSupplier","method":"subscribe","line":36},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni","method":"subscribe","line":36},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe","method":"withSubscriber","line":51},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe","method":"with","line":110},{"class":"io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe","method":"with","line":88},{"class":"io.vertx.mutiny.core.Context$1","method":"handle","line":170},{"class":"io.vertx.mutiny.core.Context$1","method":"handle","line":168},{"class":"io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase","method":"lambda$null$0","line":137},{"class":"io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal","method":"dispatch","line":264},{"class":"io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase","method":"lambda$executeBlocking$1","line":135},{"class":"io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue","method":"run","line":76},{"class":"io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14","method":"runWith","line":576},{"class":"org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task","method":"run","line":2513},{"class":"org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody","method":"run","line":1538},{"class":"org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable","method":"run","line":29},{"class":"org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable","method":"run","line":29},{"class":"io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable","method":"run","line":30},{"class":"java.lang.Thread","method":"run","line":833},{"class":"com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads","method":"threadStartRoutine","line":775},{"class":"com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads","method":"pthreadStartRoutine","line":203}],"causedBy":{"exception":{"refId":2,"exceptionType":"io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable","message":"Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster","frames":[]}}}}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T12:30:46.833+02:00","sequence":111,"loggerClassName":"io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.i18n.ProviderLogging_$logger","loggerName":"io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.provider","level":"ERROR","message":"SRMSG00201: Error caught while processing a message in method x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer#consume","threadName":"vert.x-eventloop-thread-1","threadId":38,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-instance-a-7b8bc8f87b-6254q","processId":198,"exception":{"refId":1,"exceptionType":"io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable","message":"Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster","frames":[]}}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T12:30:46.834+02:00","sequence":112,"loggerClassName":"io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.i18n.KafkaLogging_$logger","loggerName":"io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka","level":"INFO","message":"SRMSG18224: Executing consumer revoked re-balance listener for group 'prod-k8s-bpm-kafka-metrics'","threadName":"smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0","threadId":37,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-instance-a-7b8bc8f87b-6254q","processId":198}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T12:30:55.042+02:00","sequence":113,"loggerClassName":"io.smallrye.health.HealthLogging_$logger","loggerName":"io.smallrye.health","level":"INFO","message":"SRHCK01001: Reporting health down status: {\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"checks\":[{\"name\":\"SmallRye Reactive Messaging - readiness check\",\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"data\":{\"kafka\":\"[KO]\",\"application-x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer#consume\":\"[KO] - Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster\"}},{\"name\":\"Redis connection health check\",\"status\":\"UP\",\"data\":{\"default\":\"PONG\"}},{\"name\":\"Elasticsearch cluster health check\",\"status\":\"UP\",\"data\":{\"status\":\"green\"}}]}","threadName":"executor-thread-1","threadId":32,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-instance-a-7b8bc8f87b-6254q","processId":198}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T12:30:55.866+02:00","sequence":114,"loggerClassName":"io.smallrye.health.HealthLogging_$logger","loggerName":"io.smallrye.health","level":"INFO","message":"SRHCK01001: Reporting health down status: {\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"checks\":[{\"name\":\"SmallRye Reactive Messaging - liveness check\",\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"data\":{\"kafka\":\"[KO] - io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster\",\"application-x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer#consume\":\"[KO] - Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster\"}}]}","threadName":"executor-thread-1","threadId":32,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-instance-a-7b8bc8f87b-6254q","processId":198}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T12:31:05.036+02:00","sequence":115,"loggerClassName":"io.smallrye.health.HealthLogging_$logger","loggerName":"io.smallrye.health","level":"INFO","message":"SRHCK01001: Reporting health down status: {\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"checks\":[{\"name\":\"SmallRye Reactive Messaging - readiness check\",\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"data\":{\"kafka\":\"[KO]\",\"application-x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer#consume\":\"[KO] - Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster\"}},{\"name\":\"Redis connection health check\",\"status\":\"UP\",\"data\":{\"default\":\"PONG\"}},{\"name\":\"Elasticsearch cluster health check\",\"status\":\"UP\",\"data\":{\"status\":\"green\"}}]}","threadName":"executor-thread-1","threadId":32,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-instance-a-7b8bc8f87b-6254q","processId":198}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T12:31:05.866+02:00","sequence":116,"loggerClassName":"io.smallrye.health.HealthLogging_$logger","loggerName":"io.smallrye.health","level":"INFO","message":"SRHCK01001: Reporting health down status: {\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"checks\":[{\"name\":\"SmallRye Reactive Messaging - liveness check\",\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"data\":{\"kafka\":\"[KO] - io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster\",\"application-x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer#consume\":\"[KO] - Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster\"}}]}","threadName":"executor-thread-1","threadId":32,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-instance-a-7b8bc8f87b-6254q","processId":198}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T12:31:15.077+02:00","sequence":117,"loggerClassName":"io.smallrye.health.HealthLogging_$logger","loggerName":"io.smallrye.health","level":"INFO","message":"SRHCK01001: Reporting health down status: {\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"checks\":[{\"name\":\"SmallRye Reactive Messaging - readiness check\",\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"data\":{\"kafka\":\"[KO]\",\"application-x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer#consume\":\"[KO] - Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster\"}},{\"name\":\"Redis connection health check\",\"status\":\"UP\",\"data\":{\"default\":\"PONG\"}},{\"name\":\"Elasticsearch cluster health check\",\"status\":\"UP\",\"data\":{\"status\":\"green\"}}]}","threadName":"executor-thread-1","threadId":32,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-instance-a-7b8bc8f87b-6254q","processId":198}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T12:31:15.865+02:00","sequence":118,"loggerClassName":"io.smallrye.health.HealthLogging_$logger","loggerName":"io.smallrye.health","level":"INFO","message":"SRHCK01001: Reporting health down status: {\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"checks\":[{\"name\":\"SmallRye Reactive Messaging - liveness check\",\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"data\":{\"kafka\":\"[KO] - io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster\",\"application-x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer#consume\":\"[KO] - Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster\"}}]}","threadName":"executor-thread-1","threadId":32,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-instance-a-7b8bc8f87b-6254q","processId":198}
{"timestamp":"2023-07-25T12:31:15.916+02:00","sequence":119,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logging.Logger","loggerName":"io.quarkus","level":"INFO","message":"bpm-kafka-metrics stopped in 0.026s","threadName":"Shutdown thread","threadId":28,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"app-instance-a-7b8bc8f87b-6254q","processId":198}
```

But, actually, as I read logs more carefully, unhealthy state of the app was actually not reported by Redis connection being down -

`{\"name\":\"Redis connection health check\",\"status\":\"UP\",\"data\":{\"default\":\"PONG\"}}`

but because of SmallRye Reactive Messaging reporting that it had problem with consuming event -

`{\"name\":\"SmallRye Reactive Messaging - liveness check\",\"status\":\"DOWN\",\"data\":{\"kafka\":\"[KO] - io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster\",\"application-x.y.z.app.KafkaConsumer#consume\":\"[KO] - Failed to connect to all nodes of the cluster\"}}]}`

So that pushed me to use `@Retry` on my event consuming method as documented in https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#retrying-processing - and that actually did resolve this problem for me - at least in my quick tests - will let it sit for a few days wil came back with the update.

Don't get me wrong, I still think that such retrying should be done on quarkus-redis-client side (and maybe it is but I have faulty configuration?) and `@Retry` feels more like workaround than proper fix, but thats just my opinion.

Comment: We would need a reproducer to understand what's going on. Did you try to only connect to the 3 master nodes?

Comment: I updated my initial post with some tests and context. @Clement I will try it and came back with results, but I'm afraid it's not gonna change the results

Comment: Updated with only masters node config and also posted fix/workaround